# Determine the "offending" file and line number when error occurs

Tags: php

This is a bit hard to explain but the code might be clearer:

```
// class.php
class Foo
{
    public function bar ()
    {

    }
}


// test.php
$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar(); // e.g., for some reason this returns an error hence error handler will be triggered
```

This is a simplified example but the nesting of test.php could be deeper.
How can my custom error handler tell me that the error occurred in test.php line 2?

I am currently using `debug_backtrace()` but the array index of test.php is varying depending on how deep the object is or how many `require()`'s

Is there a way to pinpoint this regardless of how deep the nesting of the function call is?

Answer (score 1):

You can print a `debug_backtrace()` which will generate a complete array of all callers, including files and line numbers.

#### Example

```
<?php

    class Test {

        public function debug() {
            print_r(debug_backtrace());
        }
    }

    function print_debug() {
        $test = new Test();
        $test->debug();
    }

    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    print_debug();
```

#### Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => D:\Websites\htdocs\tests\index.php
            [line] => 11
            [function] => debug
            [class] => Test
            [object] => Test Object
                (
                )

            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => D:\Websites\htdocs\tests\index.php
            [line] => 14
            [function] => print_debug
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

---

You can also try to throw an exception, and allow it to bubble up, it will kill you script, displaying a full backtrace. See if that works for you.

Comment: As mentioned I am already using `debug_backtrace()` but if the object is several objects/requires deep the index of the offending file in the array is not always the same.

Comment: @IMB: See my edit, try to use Exceptions. Also, you can traverse the array using `next()` until you reach the file you need.

Comment: Thing is I do not know the file I need when an error occurs. For example if you call `new Test` inside another class, `debug_backtrace()` will now return 3 items, moving the offending file 1 item up. To put simply, I want the custom error handler to tell me the error happened in file x, line x, regardless of how deep the nesting is. I guess this can't be done?